# NodeJS PKG How to exclude source code from being included in plain text

Tags: node.js, compilation, exe

For various reason, including protecting my source code and just a right click to execute instead of installing node, npm ci, etc... I would like to package my nodejs app into an executable.

From my research I found

- [nexe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nexe)
- [pkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg)

I'm trying to use `pkg` because it felt easier to use after a first look at it. But on a sandbox project to test his capabilities, I came across an issue.

Considering :

```js
// /src/module.js
function bar(str) {
  let tic = "another sensitive place";
  console.log(str);
}

function foo() {
  if (true) {
    return "some really important business are done and the how should";
  }
}

module.exports = {
  bar,
  foo,
};
```

```js
// index.js
const mod = require("./src/module.js");
mod.bar(mod.foo());
```

And the pkg configuration in `package.json`

```
{
  // many lines ommited
  "bin": "index.js",
  "pkg": {
    "scripts": [
      "src/module.js",
      "index.js"
    ],
    "targets": [
      "node16-win-x64"
    ],
    "outputPath": "bin/"
  },
  // many more lines ommited
}
```

When opening the `.exe` file generated in `./bin` directory by the command `pkg .`, I can find my code in plain text. Why ? How to make pkg only include the bytecode ? And yes, I'm aware of string being plain text even in bytecode, but at least the logic around is protected.

Screenshot of `/bin/index.exe`
[clear code in generated executable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X94E0.png)

Answer (score 3):

I figured out why my code was included in plain text and in bytecode. And I though posting the answer for futur reader might be better than deleting my question.

From the documentation of [pkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg), in the `Other considerations` section :

> By default, pkg will check the license of each package and make sure that stuff that isn't meant for the public will only be included as bytecode.

I conducted more tests and if the `package.json` have either the property `private` set to `true` (or `"true"`) or the `license` property set to public license (e.g: ISC).

In my case, the `npm init` used to create my sandbox project set the license property to `ISC`.

**Removing the `licence` property from `package.json` solved the issue.**

Comment: I am in exactly similar situation currently and your information proved to be useful. I tried removing 'licence:ISC' from package.json and then rebuild, but still I could see my code at bottom.  Any idea as to why its not working ? Thanks for your information!!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your comment in my notification. I have no idea about your issue.

Comment: Looking into the generated  .exe file it seems to contain a very large chunk of plaintext JavaScript code, with Joyent copyright, I assume these are the Node.js sources.  I wonder if there's a way to package those as only binaries, would make the exe smaller and faster loading.

Comment: @PanuLogic as stated in my answer, if one of the package in the deps chain does appear to be public through the private or license property of their package.json. They will be included as code source. I think it is a behavior enforced by pkg team (see the section i am quoting in my answer).

Comment: @Skylli   I see. It just  seems to make little sense to include Node.js sources into an exe whose purpose is to provide binary EXEs for exactly  Node.js programs.   But maybe there's a legal reason for that.